# How to extend sorting order of Team Members

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-5

I'm using [Business Lounge theme](https://rtthemes.com/premium-wordpress-themes/#portfolio-55) by [RT themes](https://rtthemes.com/) with Elementor.

Wordpress version is current (5.2.1)

On the team page (Demo: https://businesslounge-demo.rtthemes.com/our-team/) there is a list of cards of team members. I want to change the order of the team members to an option that is not currently selectable.

The team member list is done with a shortcode `[staff_box]`

In Elementor edit mode I looks like this:
[image]

### Edit:

The edit form is defined in
`wp-content/plugins/businesslounge-extensions/inc/elementor-addons/staff.php`

```
<?php
namespace Elementor;
// ...
class Widget_RT_Staff extends Widget_Base {
  // ...
  protected function _register_controls() {
    // ...
    $this->add_control(
      'list_orderby',
        [
          'label'     => esc_html_x( 'List Order By', 'Admin Panel','businesslounge' ),
          'description' => esc_html_x('Sorts the posts by this parameter', 'Admin Panel','businesslounge' ),    
          'type'      =>  Controls_Manager::SELECT,
          'default'    =>  "date",
          "options"    => array(
            'date' => esc_html_x('Date',"Admin Panel","businesslounge"),
            'author' => esc_html_x('Author',"Admin Panel","businesslounge"),
            'title' => esc_html_x('Title',"Admin Panel","businesslounge"),
            'modified' => esc_html_x('Modified',"Admin Panel","businesslounge"),
            'ID' => esc_html_x('ID',"Admin Panel","businesslounge"),
            'rand' => esc_html_x('Randomized',"Admin Panel","businesslounge"),                                  
          )
        ]
      );     
      // ...
  }
  // ...
}

Plugin::instance()->widgets_manager->register_widget_type( new Widget_RT_Staff() );
```

The edit form is defined in `wp-content/plugins/businesslounge-extensions/inc/editor/staff_box.php`


like so

```
<?php
vc_map(
    array(
        'base'        => 'staff_box',
        'name'        => _x( 'Team', 'Admin Panel','businesslounge' ),
        'icon'        => 'rt_theme rt_team',
        'category'    => array(_x( 'Content', 'Admin Panel','businesslounge' ), _x( 'Theme Addons', 'Admin Panel','businesslounge' )),
        'description' => _x( 'Displays team members', 'Admin Panel','businesslounge' ),
        'params'      => array(
// ...    
          array(
            'param_name'  => 'list_orderby',
            'heading'     => _x( 'List Order By', 'Admin Panel','businesslounge' ),
            "description" => _x("Sorts the posts by this parameter",'Admin Panel','businesslounge'),
            'type'        => 'dropdown',
            "value"       => array(
                                _x('Date','Admin Panel','businesslounge') => 'date',
                                _x('Author','Admin Panel','businesslounge') => 'author',
                                _x('Title','Admin Panel','businesslounge') => 'title',
                                _x('Modified','Admin Panel','businesslounge') => 'modified',
                                _x('ID','Admin Panel','businesslounge') => 'ID',
                                _x('Randomized','Admin Panel','businesslounge') => 'rand',
                            ),
            'save_always' => true
        ),
// ...
```

The output is defined in
`wp-content/plugins/businesslounge-extensions/inc/shortcodes/staff_box.php`

like so:

```
<?php
function rt_staff( $atts, $content = null ) { 
// ...

    //defaults
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(  
        "id"           => 'staff-'.rand(100000, 1000000), 
        "class"        => "", 
        "list_layout"  => "1/1", 
        "list_orderby" => "date",
        "list_order"   => "DESC",
        "ids"          => array(),
        "box_style"    => ""        
    ), $atts));

// ...

    //general query
    $args=array( 
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'post_type'      => 'staff',
        'orderby'        => $list_orderby,
        'order'          => $list_order,
        'showposts'      => 1000                                                            
    );
// ...
    $theQuery = query_posts($args);
// ...
```

What I want to do:
Add an option `'post_name'` to the select box so that I can sort the team by a different field. I want to add
`'Post name' => 'post_name',`

How can I do this without changing the original source code?
I already have the child theme of business_lounge theme activated.
Do I need a custom extension for this?

Comment: I investigated in the code a bit more and I found that elementor has the control and I posted the wrong code of the control.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to modify the original code.
You can't override the function unless the author applied a [`filter`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/) to the value returned, or used an [`action`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action/).

As gael notes in his answer, you can soften the blow of losing changes on updates by copying the original code into your child theme's `functions.php` then renaming the function - for e.g. to `my_rt_staff()` before adding in your modifications.

You would however still need to call the `my_rt_staff()` in the plugin instead of `rt_stuff` and you would have to make this change whenever the plugin was updated, but you wouldn't lose your code.

(Perhaps you could change the `"list_orderby" => "date"` in the default shortcode attributes to `"list_orderby" => "post_name",` as default in your modified `my_rt_staff()` method so it orders by name as default instead of date)

However, this does not help much in your specific circumstance, as the ideal modification you need to make is to the control itself, on the `_register_controls()` method in the `Widget_RT_Staff` class. You can override this by extending `Widget_RT_Staff` but you would still need to call your new class which results in you modifying the plugin code.

Without seeing how the `Widget_RT_Staff` class affects the shortocde, I can't be certain this would work, but based on the `rt_staff()` method, if you use the shortcode as `[staff_box orderby="post_name"]` you may get your intended result without having to touch any code.

Comment: I can circumvent this by adding a new option to the control's select box in the browser's development tool, selecting that option and saving. The control has no validation as it seems.

Comment: I thought of the changing of the shortcode directly, but elementor somehow doesn't work with shortcodes or doesn't let me see them.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to modify your plugin without losing update abilities by 'overriding' the function as described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40856197/3623080

Make a copy of the function in your child-theme's functions.php, customize and rename it, use it in place of the original function.

Hope it will help